# How can I create stackpanels in wpf automatically without using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Newbie here.

I'm writing a code to create information for different users. I want the stackpanels to be generated automatically.

For example if 5 user enters his/her details in the ui and click on the add button, 5 stackpanel with the users info,should  be generated automatically for each users. Please what wpfcontrol can I use for this functionality? Thanks all.

```
        <StackPanel >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="32">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,6,5,0"  
                       Text="First Name" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox Name="firstname" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Margin="0,0,0,9" Width="71"/>

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="49" RenderTransformOrigin="0.502,1.031">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,6,5,0" 
                       Text="Last Name" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox Name="lastname" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Margin="0,0,0,26" Width="71" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Margin="10,10,0,0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button x:Name="Btn_add" Content="Add"  Click="Btn_add_Click"   
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="44"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="10">

                <WrapPanel Margin="0,10">
                    <TextBlock Text="Full Name: " FontWeight="Bold" />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text,     ElementName=lastname}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=firstname}" />

                </WrapPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I don't know how your user interface is intended to look at function, but it kind of sounds to me like you could probably benefit a lot by using some ItemsControl with a custom DataTemplate (which would be the ..ahem... template for the StackPanel+its content for each user presented through the ItemsControl) instead of trying to "code" the look of your user interface/presentation...

Comment: Hello thanks for the input. What I actually want to do is to generate stackpanels with the users when the user click on add button. I have edited it above

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UserControl that contains your StackPanel and of its content. You would then be able to instantiate that UserControl on-the-fly whenever you want it. See  [Creating & using a UserControl](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/usercontrols-and-customcontrols/creating-using-a-usercontrol/) for a tutorial on WPF UserControl.

Comment: Hello thanks for the input. What I want to do is to generate stackpanels with the users info

Comment: You can always build your stack panel by creating instances of the StackPanel class, and then add whatever other controls you want to it. If the controls in the StackPanel are changing depending on users, then that would be your only option.